# Half scenes with static elements, other with spawn

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I have 2D game, where half scene with spawn enemies and (for example) other half scene, where I want use static enemies and other elements.

I thought to create sript that after some time (for example 10 seconds), will stop spawn scripts , and run the movement of other elements.

**So. Maybe there is a reasonable solution to this problem.**

[UPDATE]

I need the most sensible solution of such a problem, I do not mean to do this, but how to make it better.

1) Can make static elements, which will be a certain time, just stand behind the camera, and then move ... or programmatically create static elements, over time, in advance of known locations...Or download the entire stack of elements over time.

2) Or can completely abandon this idea. A striking example is the **Subway Surf**, there static scenes (layout) are created in random order.

P.s. I hope I have explained my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just learn to use "Invoke", it's extremely simple.

```
Invoke( "YourOtherRoutine", 10f );
```

So after ten seconds it will run the other routine.  That routine could easily stop one script running, start another script running, or, whatever it is you want to do. There are tens of thousands of examples of Invoke() and InvokeRepeating() on the usual Unity forums, etc.

Comment: the purpose of my question is not just stopping and starting of another function, and other variants to create a fundamentally different pictures in one scene.

Comment: Sorry, for the inaccurate explanation of the problem. And in any case, thanks for the help)

Comment: sure, sorry. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

From your reference to Subway Surf, I assume that you want to generate static elements like the path and static trains in subway surf and non-Static elements like some moving trains. If so then I have a possible solution.

1. You can create pre-defined sets of elements (let say 20 or 30 set with different combination of elements) and then spawn them randomly one after another. e.g. have a look at the two reference images below.

[image][image]

Now, note that you might see these scenes exactly as in the images multiple times while playing the game, this is because they are pre-created, The developers behind Subway surf have created these paths and saved them as prefabs and then spawn them at different locations during game play.

2. You might have noticed that sometime the path is the same but the position of trains is different. This can be achieved by further creating spawn points on your path and then at runtime randomly select points on which you want to spawn your static elements.
3. In many cases when there are more than one gates you can pass through (I am referring to the gate in the second image). the moving trains spawns on the path of the gate you cross. Spawning the moving train can be achieved as mentioned in step two with a movement script attached to it. Regarding the question of how to know on what path to spawn there are two possible ways (that I can think of right know).

   - You can keep track of your players current lane and then spawn the train on that lane.
   - You can place separate triggers on each lane and then detect which lane trigger was triggered and then spawn the train on that lane.
4. For other moving trains just use the method in step 2 to spawn them but with a movement script attached.